Unable to Access Dockerized Application on Port 3000 in Docker Play
Description:
I'm encountering an issue while trying to access my Dockerized application running on port 3000 in Docker Play. Despite successfully deploying the container and verifying that the health check reports as healthy, I'm unable to load the application when clicking on the exposed port.
Issue Description:
Symptoms: When I click on the port 3000 link provided in Docker Play, the application fails to load. The browser displays a connection error.
Health Check Status: The health check for my Docker container reports as healthy, indicating that the application within the container is responding correctly to requests.
Steps Taken So Far:
Local Testing: Successfully tested the application locally and verified that it runs correctly on port 3000.
Deployment on Docker Play: Deployed the Docker container on Docker Play and confirmed that the container starts successfully.
Health Check: Inspected the health check status of the container and confirmed that it reports as healthy.
Browser Troubleshooting: Tried accessing the application from multiple browsers and devices to rule out any browser-specific issues.
Additional Information:
Dockerfile: My Dockerfile is configured to expose port 3000, and the application listens on port 3000 within the container.
Application Logs: Checked the logs of the Docker container for any error messages or issues reported by the application during startup, but found no relevant errors.
Network Configuration: Ensured that there are no firewall rules or network configurations blocking access to port 3000.
Computer: I'm working a Mac with M2 and therefore had to built my App with the following "docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t hello-world-app .".
Could there be a problem with the platform I'm using (Mac M2) because I followed the tutorial (https://docs.docker.com/get-started) and tried many different solutions with the original code from the tutorial and some basic code from ChatGPT. After a lot of googeling an debugging I don't know where else the issue could be. Any suggestions or insights on what might be causing the problem and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.
Dockerfile
# Use the official Node.js 16 image as a parent image
FROM node:16-alpine

# Install curl to ensure health checks can run
RUN apk add --no-cache curl

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (or npm-shrinkwrap.json) from your host to your current directory.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install --production

# Copy the rest of your application's code
COPY . .

# Inform Docker that the container listens on port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Run the command inside your image filesystem
CMD ["node", "index.js"]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=30s --start-period=5s --retries=3 \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost:3000 || exit 1

index.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});


What does your application code that sets up the network listener look like?  If you listen only on 127.0.0.1, the server won't be accessible from outside its own container, and that matches the symptom you describe.

Hey @DavidMaze, thanks for the idea. Here is the part of my index.js file, that listens:
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {   console.log(Server running on port ${PORT}); });
So I think that this is probably not the issue if it's listening on 0.0.0.0, right?
I also added my whole index.js file in my original question.
